# How to load the map for multiple robot navigation?

Tags: navigation, ros-kinetic, gmapping, map-server, amcl

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have followed the steps in answer for this [question](https://answers.ros.org/question/41433/multiple-robots-simulation-and-navigation/?answer=41434#post-id-41434) to setup multiple robot navigation. Everything is working well except when i launch the navigation the map is not loaded and getting the below error. I have remapped map to /map but still the target frame seems to be map, how is this possible.

```
[WARN] [1520794132.318544579, 556.425000000]: Timed out waiting for transform from robot2_tf/base_link to map to become available before running costmap, tf error: canTransform: target_frame map does not exist.. canTransform returned after 0.1 timeout was 0.1. 
[ WARN] [1520794132.400360318, 556.479000000]: Request for map failed; trying again...
```

So, how to load the map for multiple robots navigation and make them share the map.

My launch files are as follows:

Navigation of robots launch:

```
<launch>
  <include file="$(find gazebo_ros)/launch/empty_world.launch">
 </include>
 
  <!-- include our robots -->
  <include file="$(find robot_description)/launch/myrobots.launch"/>

  Run the map server 
  <node name="map_server" pkg="map_server" type="map_server" args="$(find robot_description)/maps/map.yaml" respawn="false" >
    <param name="frame_id" value="/map" />
  </node>

  <group ns="robot1">
    <param name="tf_prefix" value="robot1_tf" />
    <param name="amcl/initial_pose_x" value="1" />
    <param name="amcl/initial_pose_y" value="1" />
    <include file="$(find robot_description)/launch/move_base.launch" />
  </group>

  <group ns="robot2">
    <param name="tf_prefix" value="robot2_tf" />
    <param name="amcl/initial_pose_x" value="1" />
    <param name="amcl/initial_pose_y" value="-1" />
    <include file="$(find robot_description)/launch/move_base.launch" />
  </group>

</launch>
```

multiple robots launch:

```
<launch>
  <!-- No namespace here as we will share this description. 
       Access with slash at the beginning -->
<param name="robot_description" textfile="$(find robot_description)/urdf/myrobot.urdf" /> 

  <!-- BEGIN ROBOT 1-->
  <group ns="robot1">
    <param name="tf_prefix" value="robot1_tf" />
    <include file="$(find robot_description)/launch/one_robot.launch" >
      <arg name="init_pose" value="-x 1 -y 1 -z 0" />
      <arg name="robot_name"  value="Robot1" />
    </include>
  </group>

  <!-- BEGIN ROBOT 2-->
  <group ns="robot2">
    <param name="tf_prefix" value="robot2_tf" />
    <include file="$(find robot_description)/launch/one_robot.launch" >
      <arg name="init_pose" value="-x 1 -y -1 -z 0" />
      <arg name="robot_name"  value="Robot2" />
    </include>
  </group>
</launch>
```

Move_base launch:

```
<launch>    
  <!--- Run AMCL -->
  <include file="$(find amcl)/examples/amcl_diff.launch" />

  <!-- Define your move_base node -->
  <node pkg="move_base" type="move_base" respawn="false" name="move_base" output="screen">
    <rosparam file="$(find robot_description)/src/costmap_common_params.yaml" command="load" ns="global_costmap"/>
    <rosparam file="$(find robot_description)/src/costmap_common_params.yaml" command="load" ns="local_costmap" />
    <rosparam file="$(find robot_description)/src/local_costmap_params.yaml"  command="load" />
    <rosparam file="$(find robot_description)/src/global_costmap_params.yaml" command="load" />
    <rosparam file="$(find robot_description)/src/base_local_planner_params.yaml" command="load" />

  <remap from="map" to="/map" />
  </node>
</launch>
```

Edit 2:
Tf frames:
[image: image description]

rqt_graph:
[image: image description]

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/285062/how-to-load-the-map-for-multiple-robot-navigation?/) by [Kishore Kumar](https://answers.ros.org/users/20863/kishore-kumar/) on ROS Answers with karma: 173 on 2018-03-11

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2018-03-11**:
Can you please update your question with the relevant launch files?

**Comment by [Kishore Kumar](https://answers.ros.org/users/20863/kishore-kumar/) on 2018-03-14**:
I have edited the question as per your request

**Comment by [Igor Muniz](https://answers.ros.org/users/34375/igor-muniz/) on 2018-03-28**:
I have the same problem here. Has anyone managed to solve it?

**Comment by [nightwish](https://answers.ros.org/users/35698/nightwish/) on 2018-06-05**:
Did you resolve this problem?
I am encountering the same problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I managed to deal with this problem and figured out that the problem was fixed by setting amcl's **use_map_topic** param to **true**.

```
<node pkg="amcl" type="amcl" name="amcl" output="screen">
         ...
         <param name="use_map_topic" value="true"/>
         ... 
</node>
```

Hope this can help anyone with the same problem.

---

Originally posted by [nightwish](https://answers.ros.org/users/35698/nightwish/) with karma: 61 on 2018-06-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [topkek](https://answers.ros.org/users/34642/topkek/) on 2018-06-25**:
didnt help me :(

**Comment by [nightwish](https://answers.ros.org/users/35698/nightwish/) on 2018-06-27**:
@topkek could you give some information such as launch file, tf tree, error messages in terminal?

**Comment by [topkek](https://answers.ros.org/users/34642/topkek/) on 2018-06-29**:
main launch file https://pastebin.com/yQMru4Pj
move base file https://pastebin.com/V6QzeRHP
errors https://pastebin.com/pn6ZgZLV
tf tree looks like the one from the question

**Comment by [nightwish](https://answers.ros.org/users/35698/nightwish/) on 2018-06-29**:
Thank you for the information. From the error in terminal I think you need a transform tree as following
**map->odom->[your name space]/odom**. You can use **static_transform_publisher** to do this.

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2018-06-29**:
@topkek please ask a new question. The comments section isn't the appropriate place for this.

**Comment by [topkek](https://answers.ros.org/users/34642/topkek/) on 2018-06-29**:
map_server doesnt event load any map https://i.imgur.com/W4HtsSu.jpg

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2018-06-29**:
If this is related to your other question, #q294240, then please move the discussion there. Otherwise, please create a new question.

**Comment by [topkek](https://answers.ros.org/users/34642/topkek/) on 2018-06-29**:
ok. i had so many questions and never got an answer...

**Comment by [nightwish](https://answers.ros.org/users/35698/nightwish/) on 2018-06-29**:
@topkek please update as my comment in your question.